# Nix flake equivalent for `nix build` on older non flake projects?

Tags: nix, nixos, nix-flake

Previously I could `nix build` a project / derivation with a default.nix file.

However after upgrading to Nixos 22.05, and hence Nix 2.8+ running `nix build` results in:

```hs
path '/example/lib' does not contain a 'flake.nix', searching up
error: path '/example/lib' is not part of a flake (neither it nor its parent directories contain a 'flake.nix' file)
```

Is there some way I can run / build this as before with nix 2.8, without having to modify the project (integrate it with the flakes functionality)? Perhaps a blank/default flake.nix file I could reference in the command? As an alternative I can run `nix-env -if default.nix` which builds the project however it also adds it to the user profile.

Comment: There's `nix-build`. I didn't know about the previous `nix build` behavior. Does `nix build -f default.nix` not work?